# C# Web Api debugging with VsCode (Mac)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, coreclr

Good day

I am currently trying to determine how to *debug* web api applications within VsCode on a Mac.

In my **project.json** I compile with DEBUG flag turned on, as per below:

```
"configurations": {
  "Debug": {
    "compilationOptions": {
       "define": [
         "DEBUG",
         "TRACE"
       ]
     }
  }
}
```

Then in **launch.json**, my current configuration is below but fails to work. That is, the service starts up but "breakpoints" are not adhered to.

```
{
 "name": ".NET Core Attach",
 "type": "coreclr",
 "request": "attach",
 "preLaunchTask": "dnx --debug web",
 "processName": "lucid"
}
```

I've even tried a build task using the same shell command (dnx --debug web) and same result.

Any assistance or guidance leading me closer to a resolution will assist.

Thanks

Comment: According to the limited documentation, debugging is only supported for Mono and .NET Core RC2, so your RC1 attempt might not work by design.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you for the response ;) Do you have the reference article or http link?

Comment: you can always start from http://code.visualstudio.com or Google.

Comment: @LexLi that's were I've been ;) Not found any docs and been scouring since yesterday. Thanks for the info nonetheless.

Comment: It involves multiple pages, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode/Debuggers and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/10/experimental-net-core-debugging-in-vs-code/

Comment: Thank I see ;) Guess I'll wait a while for that to mature, losing intellisense doesn't sound fun.